# Implicit Template Parameters

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, implicit

The following code generates a compile error in Xcode:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(T Value)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo MyFoo(123);
    return 0;
}
```

`error: missing template arguments before 'MyFoo'`

Changing `Foo MyFoo(123);` to `Foo<int> MyFoo(123);` fixes the issue, but shouldn't the compiler be able to figure out the appropriate datatype?

Is this a compiler bug, or am I misunderstanding implicit template parameters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The constructor could in theory infer the type of the object it is constructing, but the statement:

```
Foo MyFoo(123);
```

Is allocating temporary space for `MyFoo` and must know the fully-qualified type of `MyFoo` in order to know how much space is needed.

If you want to avoid typing (i.e. with fingers) the name of a particularly complex template, consider using a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::string> StringMap;
```

Or in C++0x you could use the `auto` keyword to have the compiler use type inference--though many will argue that leads to less readable and more error-prone code, myself among them. ;p

Comment: if it could infer the type, it could infer the space.

Comment: It can infer the type for the call to the constructor, but not for the storage space. If you define a variable as simply `Foo`, can it hold both `Foo<int>` and `Foo<std::string>`? Or does it always know it's secretly a `Foo<int>` in its heart of hearts? If the variable were `const` then it could be implemented, since the value could not be reassigned, but then we'd have different lexical rules for `const T` vs `T` and great havoc would ensue.

Comment: "typing (i.e with fingers)" is a gem :D

Answer (score 8):

compiler can figure out template parameter type only for templated functions, not for classes/structs

Comment: After all, there is a reason for the function `std::make_pair<typename T, typename U>(T t, U u)` even though we already have the class `std::pair<typename T, typename U>`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, it's non-existing feature. You have to fully specify class/structure template arguments during instantiation, always, the types are not inferred as they can be for function templates.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler can deduce the template argument such case:

```
template<typename T>
void fun(T param)
{
    //code...
}

fun(100);    //T is deduced as int;
fun(100.0);  //T is deduced as double
fun(100.0f); //T is deduced as float

Foo<int> foo(100);
fun(foo);    //T is deduced as Foo<int>;

Foo<char> bar('A');
fun(bar);    //T is deduced as Foo<char>;
```

Actually template argument deduction is a huge topic. Read this article at ACCU:

[The C++ Template Argument Deduction](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/409)

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can use `decltype`:

```
int myint = 123;
Foo<decltype(myint)> MyFoo(myint);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do now works in C++ 17.  Template parameters can be inferred in C++ 17.

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(T Value)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo a(123);
    Foo b = 123;
    Foo c {123};
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes a lot of sense it is like this, as Foo is not a class, only `Foo<T>` where T is a type.

In C++0x you can use auto, and you can create a function to make you a Foo, let's call it foo (lower case f). Then you would do

```
template<typename T> Foo<T> foo(int x)
{
  return Foo<T>(x);
}

auto myFoo = foo(55);
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant: "template<typename T> Foo<T> foo(T x)"?